# Ionic ion-tabs Keep Overlaying My Page Overlay Div

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I have tabs and I am trying to make an overlaying div... but tabs can't let this happen

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-s6qxwm?file=pages/home/home.css

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

SS:

[image]

What can I do please to achieve overlaying the whole view?

Comment: User `ion-modal` on your home page it will cover your tabs.

Comment: did you try the <ion-backdrop>?

Answer (score 0):

Scoping of your css with the default ShadowDom configurations are getting in the way. You can put your style globally (apps) and it will work.

[https://ionic-5b8qcq.stackblitz.io](https://ionic-5b8qcq.stackblitz.io/)

```js
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.css'],
    })
```

You can modify **ViewEncapsalation**, but it would be better practice to use a global utility approach (service or directive) to propagate the state change and update the appropriate scoped element.

Comment: I want the div to be at home.html as I do much operations over it.

Comment: In that case you will need to restructure things as the default shadow dom configurations are going to mess up the css scoping - viia shadow dom. Ii'll see if Ii can update the answer with a few options for you; i'm thinking you can leverage a style directive, updating the component shadow dom's default configurations, or just include it as a global style (the ionic way). I'll update my answer with some options

Comment: let me think with you... what about view encapsulation to home css only??

Comment: Would you be open to trigger an event from home that can propagate to a parent control (tabs) or a handler  that subscribed to the event ? This would get around having to remove Shadow dom.

Comment: You can use ViewEncapsulation.None, but you will need to make sure you reference the css parent element. Here is a quick example to illustrate, but it certainly can be improved. I'm not advising this method, but showing you one example vs the global  style rule approach- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5b8qcq?file=pages/home/home.css

Comment: I made the service for overlay and put it in app.component.html and it working perfectly across the app now, if you can edit the answer to keep tabs behind too, or using my technique I will be happy to accept it as the correct answer, thanks for the hint <3

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. I modified the answer a bit, let me know if that is what you were looking for. I wasn't sure what you meant by leaving tabs behind,  but happy to make that edit too.